# Heroku pg:push puts my tables in wrong schma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, push

It looks like heroku pg:push has put all my data into a schema named for my local db, and not in public where they'd be accessible to my app.

How do I fix this?

```
       Schema       |             Name             | Type  |     Owner      
--------------------+------------------------------+-------+----------------
 information_schema | sql_features                 | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_implementation_info      | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_languages                | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_packages                 | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_parts                    | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_sizing                   | table | postgres
 information_schema | sql_sizing_profiles          | table | postgres
 lorax_development  | ac_coa                       | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | acbkacct                     | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | accommodation                | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | accommodation_copy           | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | address                      | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | advert                       | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | affiliation                  | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | agency                       | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | always                       | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | answer                       | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | ar_internal_metadata         | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | best_month                   | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 lorax_development  | bklin                        | table | iykrnaofpnlzod
 ...
```